# Using CMake's ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND for pre-compilation processing

Tags: cmake

My project is made up of a number of components. Each one depends on one or more `*.hpp` files which are generated from an `*.lcm` using an external tool. I'd like to be able to specify a list of which `*.lcm` files are required for each component and have CMake automatically do the compilation when required, perhaps specified using a nice little macro:

```
REQUIRED_LCMS (the_component x.lcm z.lcm)
```

For the compilation of an `*.lcm`, I think the following should work:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND (OUTPUT  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${lcm_basename}.hpp
                    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${lcm}
                    COMMAND "lcm-gen"
                    ARGS    "--lazy --cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${lcm}"
                    COMMENT "  ${lcm} -> ${lcm_basename}.hpp")
```

...but I'm unsure of what should be in `REQUIRED_LCMS`. The [`ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) and an [`ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_target)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working, without the fine-grained (i.e. per-lcm file dependency) by doing the following:

```
SET (LCM_MESSAGES x.lcm
                  y.lcm
                  z.lcm)

SET (LCM_COMPILED_MESSAGES)
FOREACH (_file ${LCM_MESSAGES})

  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT (_filewe ${_file} NAME_WE)
  STRING (TOUPPER ${_filewe} _FILEWE)
  SET (_filehpp ${_filewe}.hpp)
  SET (_filehpp_output ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${_filehpp})

  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND (OUTPUT  ${_filehpp_output}
                      DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_file}
                      COMMAND lcm-gen
                      ARGS    --lazy --cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_file})

  LIST (APPEND LCM_COMPILED_MESSAGES ${_filehpp_output})

ENDFOREACH ()

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET (LCM_MESSAGES DEPENDS ${LCM_COMPILED_MESSAGES})
```

...and then in the CMakeLists.txt of each component:

```
ADD_DEPENDENCIES (the_component LCM_MESSAGES)
```

Comment: This answer is pretty good, with one catch.  Including the output of a custom command in the list of sources for a target will add a dependency automatically, so if you put ${LCM_COMPILED_MESSAGES} in your list of sources for the targets that use it, the dependency will be automatic.  The downside of this approach as opposed to the custom-target one is that it will show the generated files in your IDE source list, if applicable, and I think it might need to be in the same directory (same CMakeLists.txt file) as the custom command.